# Datatable: bind column width

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

How to bind column width for PrimeNG data table?

Neither this works:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="rows">
    <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols2" [field]="col.FieldName" [header]="col.Caption" [style.width.px]="col.Width" >
```

nor this:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="rows" >
    <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols2" [field]="col.FieldName" [header]="col.Caption" [style]="col.Style" >
```

Width of column cannot be defined like this:

```
[style]="{width: '180px', 'text-align': 'center'}"
```

because it is dynamic.

Comment: I am not familiar with primeng. But why `[style.width.px]` and not `[style.width]`? Why .px? Doesn't seem right.

Comment: That syntax is on Angular main page: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When building your columns, set Style as an object.  This worked for me:

```
cols2: ColumnSettings[] = [
    {
        FieldName: 'Name',
        Caption: 'Caption',
        Style: { 'width': '180px', 'text-align': 'center' }
    },
    ....
];
```

Comment: @bmi Glad to hear it helped, it took me a while of messing around with it to figure this out, it was not clear from the documentation I was reading.  I would ideally like to find an autowidth setting for the table but I have been unable to do that.  Can you accept this answer if it works for you, so that others can find it?

Answer (score 1):

**Varying column width**
Use following solution to set individual column width:

```
<p-column field="vin" header="Vin" [style]="{'width': someColWidthVariable }"></p-column>
```

You can specify as `[style]="{'width':'22px'}"` or `[style]="{'width':'20%'}"` as well or bind to some variable. An example would be

```
<p-dataTable>
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols2" [field]="col.fieldName" 
         [header]="col.Caption" [style]="{'width': col.width }">
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

**Autofit Columns**
If you want Autofit columns so that the width is adjusted automatically based on contents then set the table-layout to auto. By default it is 'fixed' in primeng, which means column width is evenly distributed.

e.g.

```
<p-dataTable [tableStyle]="{'table-layout':'auto'}" class="composite-table" [(value)]="model.calcLines"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[tableStyle]="{width: '180px','text-align':'center'}"
```

notice that text-align needs to be `'text-align'` not `text-align`

```
<p-dataTable  [tableStyle]="{width: '180px','text-align':'center'}"  >
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols2" [field]="col.fieldName" 
         [header]="col.Caption">
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

### Here is a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UMH1DzQP9TA5C7aolCTm?p=preview)

Comment: Every column has his own width and I don't know columns width. In my case Primeng datatable get metadata of every column from web service. It is impossible write fixed column width into angular component template. I know if I write fixed column width into component template it works. But I need bind column width (whole style) by data from web api service. How to do this?

Comment: Okay, that was a bit unclear, I understood that you just didn't get the code to work at all, and that you wanted a fixed width ;) Can't say from the top of my head now how that would work as you want. Have to look at it a bit more :)

Comment: I need something like this - dynamic setting of style:


<p-dataTable>
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols2" [field]="col.fieldName" 
         [header]="col.Caption" [style]="col.Style" >
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a table width like this

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3" [responsive]="true" [stacked]="stacked" [style]="{'width': '500px'}">
    <p-header>Responsive</p-header>
    <p-column field="vin" header="Vin"></p-column>
    <p-column field="year" header="Year"></p-column>
    <p-column field="brand" header="Brand"></p-column>
    <p-column field="color" header="Color"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

If you know how many column you will have then you can arrange according to that like if you need two columns from 180px then set table width to 360 px and you will have two equal columns which has 180px width.

Comment: Every column has his own width and I don't know columns width. In my case Primeng datatable get metadata of every column from web service. It is impossible write fixed column width into angular component template. I know if I write fixed column width into component template it works. But I need bind column width (whole style) by data from web api service. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

assign the style in the .ts file like below "Style"

`this.cols = [
        { field: 'tableName', header: 'Table Name', Style: {width: '180px', 'text-align': 'center'}, sort : 'true' },`

.....

then add the name dynamic in the loop

`<p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [style]="col.Style" [sortable]="col.sort"></p-column>`